# Problem to find the Maximum likelihood estimates of parameters of generalized normal distribution in R

Tags: r, optimization, mle

First  I estimated the parameters of exponentiated generalized normal distribution using the dataset (data1: generated from normal distribution). Then I used real dataset (data2) and tried to find the maximum likelihood estimates (MLE) using the *AdequacyModel* packages. It gives the error message (mentioned right below the code).

1. Why does the same code estimate for first dataset (data1), but it doesn't estimate for the second dataset (data2)?
2. Is my way of plugging the baseline distribution (normal) in generalized class of distributions **F(x)= [1-(1-G(x))^beta]^gamma** introduced by Cordeiro et al.(2013) in R environment right? Am I defining the cdf and pdf of an generalized normal distribution in R in right way?

```
# For first dataset
data1 <- rnorm(100)
pdf_exps <- function(par,x){
beta = par[1]
gamma= par[2]
mean = par[3]
sd = par[4]
     ( beta*gamma* ((1-(1-(pnorm(x,mean,sd)))^beta)^(gamma-1)) * ((1-   
     (pnorm(x,mean,sd)))^(beta-1)) ) * (dnorm(x,mean,sd)) 
}

cdf_exps <- function(par,x){
beta = par[1]
gamma= par[2]
mean = par[3]
sd = par[4]
( 1-(1-(pnorm(x,mean,sd)))^beta)^gamma 
}

set.seed(1)
result = goodness.fit(pdf = pdf_exps, cdf = cdf_exps,
starts = c(1,1,1,1),data = data1  , method = "BFGS",
domain = c(-Inf,Inf), lim_inf = c(0,0,0,0),
lim_sup = c(2,2,2,2), S = 250, prop=0.1, N=50)
result$mle
[1]   0.5976990 0.1541794 1.0073006 0.4689187

 # For second data set
 data2 <-c( 20.56, 20.67, 21.86, 21.88, 18.96, 21.04, 21.69, 20.62, 22.64, 19.44, 25.75, 21.20,
  22.03, 25.44, 22.63, 21.86, 22.27, 21.27, 23.47, 23.19, 23.17, 24.54, 22.96, 19.76,
  23.36, 22.67, 24.24, 24.21, 20.46, 20.81, 20.17, 23.06, 24.40, 23.97, 22.62, 19.16,
  21.15, 21.40, 21.03, 21.77, 21.38, 21.47, 24.45, 22.63, 22.80, 23.58, 20.06, 23.01,
  24.64, 18.26, 24.47, 23.99, 26.24, 20.04, 25.72, 25.64, 19.87, 23.35, 22.42, 20.42,
  22.13, 25.17, 23.72, 21.28, 20.87, 19.00, 22.04, 20.12, 21.35, 28.57, 26.95, 28.13,
  26.85, 25.27, 31.93, 16.75, 19.54, 20.42, 22.76, 20.12, 22.35, 19.16, 20.77, 19.37,
  22.37, 17.54, 19.06, 20.30, 20.15, 25.36, 22.12, 21.25, 20.53, 17.06, 18.29, 18.37,
  18.93, 17.79, 17.05, 20.31, 22.46, 23.88, 23.68, 23.15, 22.32, 24.02, 23.29, 25.11,
 22.81, 26.25, 21.38, 22.52, 26.73, 23.57, 25.84, 24.06, 23.85, 25.09, 23.84, 25.31,
 19.69, 26.07, 25.50, 23.69, 26.79, 25.61, 25.06, 24.93, 22.96, 20.69, 23.97, 24.64,
 25.93, 23.69, 25.38, 22.68, 23.36, 22.44, 22.57, 19.81, 21.19, 20.39, 21.12, 21.89,
 29.97, 27.39, 23.11, 21.75, 20.89, 22.83, 22.02, 20.07, 20.15, 21.24, 19.63, 23.58,
 21.65, 25.17, 23.25, 32.52, 22.59, 30.18, 34.42, 21.86, 23.99, 24.81, 21.68, 21.04,
 23.12, 20.76, 23.13, 22.35, 22.28, 23.55, 19.85, 26.51, 24.78, 33.73, 30.18, 23.31,
 24.51, 25.37, 23.67, 24.28, 25.82, 21.93, 23.38, 23.07, 25.21, 23.25, 22.93, 26.86,
 21.26, 25.43, 24.54, 27.79, 23.58, 27.56, 23.76, 22.01, 22.34, 21.07)
pdf_exps <- function(par,x){
beta = par[1]
gamma= par[2]
mean = par[3]
sd = par[4]
           ( beta*gamma* ((1-(1-(pnorm(x,mean,sd)))^beta)^(gamma-1)) * 
   ((1-(pnorm(x,mean,sd)))^(beta-1)) ) * (dnorm(x,mean,sd)) 
 }

cdf_exps <- function(par,x){
beta = par[1]
gamma= par[2]
mean = par[3]
sd = par[4]
( 1-(1-(pnorm(x,mean,sd)))^beta)^gamma 
}

set.seed(1)
result = goodness.fit(pdf = pdf_exps, cdf = cdf_exps,
starts = c(1,1,1,1),data = data2  , method = "BFGS",
domain = c(-Inf,Inf), lim_inf = c(0,0,0,0),
lim_sup = c(2,2,2,2), S = 250, prop=0.1, N=50)
result$mle
```

```
 Error in optim(par = starts, fn = likelihood, x = data, method = "BFGS",  
:non-finite finite-difference value [1]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question is very messy, and you actually do not ask any question. Stack overflow is not a site where free solutions are provided by paid individuals, but more a site where people spend their free-time answering questions in order to help. I suggest reading [how to make a great reproducible R example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and [how do i ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), after which you should edit your question, if you wish to improve your chances for an answer.

Comment: @Oliver I did edit it,

Comment: This made it a lot more clear for me J.H. I believe your term Exponentiated Normal Distribution likely is not the correct name. I have made a edit of your post, (waiting in peer review until accepted / rejected by another reviewer) trying to clarify the question and suggesting a title that might draw more attention to your question.